# How to render my external html file inside the div element in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have tried **`@Html.Raw(Model)`** but it renders only the plain html. The css styles are not embedded in view.

How to render a Html file inside the div with the css styles?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that, but not sure whether it's included the css.

```
@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Index.html")))
```

Suggest you to create the partial view and call it in your view page.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Index")
```